# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded SonarQube

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, garbage-collection, sonarqube

I have a Jenkins job that is invoking SonarQube 6.2 via a gradle build script that constantly runs out of memory:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Some background on my SonarQube Server:

- AWS EC2
- 4Gb Ram
- 2vCpu
- MySQL 5.6

My sonar properties for the COMPUTE ENGINE is as follows:

```
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx2560m -Xms853m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
sonar.ce.workerCount=1
```

In my gradle build script I have defined the following options

```
def gradler(tasks) {
    def gradleParams = '--stacktrace -PdockerRepository=x.x.x.x:5000 -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Djvm_opts="-Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m" -Prelease.stage=BRANCH'
    sh "./gradlew ${gradleParams} ${tasks}"
}
```

With all the tunings I am still having this error. Are my gradleParams defined correctly? Are there any other parameters I need to be passing to gradle build script?

Comment: Is it the Sonarqube server or the code analysis job, which is failing? What kind of project are you analysing? Which plugins are installed on the server?

Comment: The code analysis in particular findBugs is failing on analysis of Java projects.

Comment: Installed plugins are Bitbucket Auth for SonarQube, CSS/SCSS/Less, FindBugs 3.4.4, Groovy, PMD, JSON, XML, JavaScript, and Java Properties.

Comment: Can you provide logs from analysis? Lines around the place where error occurs should be enough

Comment: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
 ... 58 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
 at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:163)
 ... 91 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
 at org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass.getAllInterfaces(JavaClass.java:873)

Comment: Put logs into the question, so I can make this an answer.  The memory problem seems to be related to the Findbugs plugin. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Yes. The current version of Findbugs version is 3.0.1 is installed.

Comment: Try to remove Findbugs plugin, to see if the analysis pass without it. If yes, you can try to exclude the file, which is causing problem to Findbugs. To replace Findbugs you can use SonarJava analyzer supplied by default with SonarQube, it's equivalent if not superior to the functionality provided by Findbugs (disclaimer I work on SonarJava analyzer in my daily job)